# Why I can't import class declared in __init__.py?

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I'm trying to clean up my flask app and I decided to use a boilerplate structure. I have the `auth_bp` blueprint, it's defined in auth.py , I have the following folder structure;

```
-app_root
 -application
   -__init__.py
   - auth.py
   - other files like template and static
 - config.py (for configuration)
 - server.py (to run the app through flask_script )
```

In `__init__.py`  I have two classes: `app` and `mail`  and I need to use them in my `auth.py` file.

But when I write :

```
from application import app, mail
```

I get an `ImportError: cannot import name app`

Here's the code in `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail
import config
from auth import auth_bp

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object("config.Config")
mail = Mail(app)
app.register_blueprint(auth_bp)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "homepage"
```

**Edit** : **Solved:** I had to import auth after creating the app and mail object.

Comment: Could you provide us with the codes you have in __init__.py? I think I might be able to help you with this issue.

Comment: @MassoudHosseinali I just added the code of init